# Trying to Create a Button to Open a Fragment (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

So I basically have a button in 'DemosFragment' and when I click it, I want it to open another fragment (SettingsFragment), I understand now that I need an activity to fix this issue, as the button currently has an onClick method using intent/startActivity, so how would I go about creating an activity that just holds my fragment? I know that may sound weird they way I wrote it, I just started Android development, but basically I have a fragment and because I want a fragment to have a button to open another fragment, I figure I need an activity for the fragment I am trying to open, so how do I create that activity and what do I need to put in it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you already loaded this fragment in an activity or have you just coded a fragment and need to know how to display that fragment as well as switch to the next one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an activity with the following code:

```
public class ShowFragmentActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_fragment);
    }
}
```

You also have to create a layout xml file called activity_show_fragment.xml in your res/layout folder:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.example.yourFragmentsClassName"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

This should work for just displaying your fragment.
To launch the activity, paste this code in your button's onClick method:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ShowFragmentActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

It's always a good decision to look at the official docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html.
Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, with a couple tweaks to your code I got it to work, except now my tabs on the top are not showing when I switch to the fragment, is there a way to get the tabs to still appear?

Answer (score 0):

Wow! Your question requires a long answer, however is a good practice (and madatory too) that Fragments cannot communicates between each others, but they can be hosted by an Activity; in that case an Activity can manage the communication flow between them (fragments) and can be developed in several ways, Bundle, Intent and the Handler. Have a look to the ufficial Android documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The [android docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) section on building a flexible UI is a good example of how to start/load a `Fragment` from an `Activity`. In the example you will see that a `FrameLayout` in the `Activity` XML is used a the fragment container. This will be the `View` in which all of your fragments are displayed.

When you load your fragment with a `FragmentTransaction` the contents of your fragments layout will be displayed in the container View. In the above referenced example this takes place with `SupportFragmentManager` a class included with the android support library, for facilitating fragment transactions in earlier version of the operating system. SupportFramgnetManager requires that you extend `FramentActivity` and not just `Activity`. If you're not worried about backwards compatibility and are extending activity, not fragment activity, you can simply use getFragmentManager() instead.

```
 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
```

After the initial add transaction you can switch between fragments using the replace method for your fragment transaction. Replace does exactly what it sounds like, it swaps one fragment for another. To accomplish this from within your firstframgnet use

```
 SecondFragment secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
 getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment).commit();
```

Notice that from within the fragment I used getActivity(). This allows you to reference the context of the host activity to access the fragment manager. When you are within the activity you do not need to use getactivity because the fragment manager is already accessible from that context.